# PHP Carry session over without www

Tags: php, session, cookies

I have a script encoded with ironcube and when I login into that script it creates a session for the domain with the www. only. So if i enter mydomain.com the session changes and I cant access session variables for WWW.mydomain.com.

I would have added the appropriate script so it creates a session for both with the www. and without but the script is encoded with ironcube.

So my problem is, I need to access sessions created with the WWW.mydomain.com from mydomain.com.

Any assistance would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

That is a security measure implemented by browsers to prevent cookie stealing.
The workaround, is to set the cookie for the top-level-domain.

If you have domains `www.example.com` and `example.com` use the following code in the beginning of your PHP files.

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.example.com');
```

Comment: That hasnt been working for me, I believe its because the session/cookie would have already been set in the encoded script, so when I add ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.domain.com');  in my own script it still doesnt access the session variables that have already been set.

Comment: @ShaunShoriwaBenjamin, I can safely assume that `.domain.com` is being translated to your actual domain, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Session is the wrong term. What you are referring to are cookies. You need to set the cookie so that its on the domain `.mydomain.com`

Answer (score 0):

Write another script that runs in the www domain that will take the value of the cookie and write it toeaanother cookie in the domain.com so that your scripts there can access it.

Comment: Thats the thing I cant access the value of the cookies across domains

Comment: Why not? It is stored in a cookie. Just write a script and put it in the www domain. This script will be able to access the session and cookies.